# Why is the TaskFactory.StartNew method not generic?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-extensions

The idomatic way to start a new side-effect-only task (that is: a task that returns no result) using the TPL in .NET 4.0 is using the following API:

```
Task Task.Factory.StartNew(Action<object>, object)
```

But why doesn't the signature of this API look like this

```
Task Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(Action<T>, T)
```

or like this

```
Task Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(T, Action<T>)
```

Technical reasons or some other reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, now that I understand the question properly :)

I believe it's because this is meant to be a [direct replacement for `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/27/9913610.aspx). I do agree that it seems somewhat odd... but *if* you're using lambda expressions anyway, it's probably easier to use the version that *does* take a state parameter (i.e. `Action` instead of `Action<object>`) and just capture the value you're interested in beforehand. It doesn't help if you're specifying the value and the function separately :(

Comment: Yes, but Task<T> is generic in the result type (TResult) of a task, but not generic in the type of the "initial state" (that is: the input for a task).

Comment: So... when I call Task.Factory.StartNew does it grab a thread from the threadpool automagically?

Comment: @Padu: Yes, I believe so - although you can have your own task factory which uses a different set of threads, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

According to a post by Stephen Toub (MSFT), they are assuming that we are going to rely on closures to pass state data.  There was also some excuse about signature ambiguity.  (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/1988294c-de41-476a-a104-aa550b7409f5)

However, relying on closures to solve this problem seems like a temporary hack waiting for a better solution.  It works, but it's not a good longer-term solution.  There are many times that simply specifying a delegate method as the action would be the simplest approach, but that means we have to use global vars or we're excluded from state parameter passing.

I like one of Hugo's proposals (from the MS forum posting).  Hugo suggested introducing a TaskState type, which seems like a clever way to circumvent the generics ambiguity issue.

Applying this to the Task.Factory.StartNew() signature and the Task() constructor as such:

```
  public Task<T>( Action<T> function, TaskState<T> state );
  public Task<T,TResult>( Func<T,TResult> function, TaskState<T> state );
```

ActionState would be a lot like the Nullable class -- just a simple wrapper around a Value member.  In practice, using TaskState might look like this:

```
  var myTask = new Task( MyMethod, new TaskState( stateInfo ) );
  ...

  public void MyMethod( StateInfo stateInfo ) { ... }
```

The TaskState<> solution is not perfect, but it seems like a much better solution than relying on closure of type casting.

Comment: Funny, the TPL team just released a [white paper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235962.aspx) about the improvements in 4.5; in the "best practices" section (p. 11), they describe that it is best to pass in the state explictly (via the Action<object> overload) instead of capturing variables in the closure. Now, with regard to this recommendation, a generic overload would be certainly desireable.